# Javascript not acquiring field value

Tags: javascript

I have 2 php pages, htmldisp.php and classfn.php. And an alert used in hrmldisp.php is not working. It should actually give a dropdown value.

htmldisp.php is

```
 <?php include("classfn.php"); $obj=new hello;?> 
 <script language="javascript">
  function submitted(){
   var select=document.getElementById('newdrop').value; 
  alert(select);    
 }
 </script>

<?php 
$id="newdrop";
echo $obj->hellofn($id); ?>
<input type="submit" onclick="submitted();"
```

classfn.php is

```
   <?php
   class hello{
function hellofn($id){  

    $s="select `Name`,`Value` from `Days`;
    $q=mysql_query($s);
    $p='<td>'.'<select id="$id">';
            while($re=mysql_fetch_array($q)){ 
            $value=$re["Value"];
            $name=$re["Name"];
            $p.='<option value="' . $value . '"' . ( $selected==$value ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ) . '>' . $name . '</option>';
            }
    $p.='</select>'.'</td>';

    return $p;
    } 
           ?>
```

The problem is alert(select) not working. Thanks

Comment: How is it not working?  Is it throwing an error, displaying 'undefined', not firing?

Comment: it is not because it is not firing, but that $id="newdrop" is not acquired by js @GrailsGuy

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you never call the function `submitted`.  On top of that your HTML is completely malformed.  You have a bunch of html and javascript outside of your `html` tag.  And you have 2 opening `html` tags with no close...